# How can I install getent on Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, macports

I have several scripts which require the utility `getent`. In addition, I've read several handy tips [which use getent](https://serverfault.com/questions/303716/linux-command-line-utility-to-resolve-host-names-using-etc-hosts-first).

`getent` is a Networking utility which is widely available on Unix, *BSD and Linux-based systems. This tool is commonly used by Sysadmins and power users to lookup network information (IP addresses, etc). As far as hostnames go, `getent` is one of the few tools which use both `/etc/hosts` and DNS.

As [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getent):

> getent is a unix command that helps a user get entries in a number of
>   important text files called databases.

The important thing here is that `getent` will search the same name services in the same order as would most applications on a unix-like system. This makes it invaluable when debugging system or application trouble.
Tools like `dig` and `nslookup` specifically look at DNS only, while `dscl` expects you to spell out the name services you want to search.

I would like to use `getent` for two testcases:

1. [Parse `/etc/hosts` before querying DNS](http://www.itworld.com/nls_unixgetent041202). For example, if I add `testhost.example.org` to `/etc/hosts`, then `getent hosts testhost.example.org` should use the entry from `/etc/hosts` before querying DNS.
2. [Query LDAP using getent](http://www.dice.inf.ed.ac.uk/doc/howto/using_ldap.html)

MacPorts does not seem to provide a package providing `getent`.

Does `getent` exist on Snow Leopard?

Comment: What is `getent`? What does it do? What systems is it typically available on?

Comment: There's no 1:1 mapping for `getent` on OS X because OS X uses [DirectoryService](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=LeopardServerReview-LocalDirectory) to do resolution on things like hostnames. Can you give some specific `getent` use examples? It'd make showing you the corresponding way to get that information on OS X easier.

Comment: @CajunLuke : `getent` is typically available on Unix, *BSD and Linux-like systems. I updated my question.

Comment: So what is it you're trying to do with `getent`? Resolve host names from `/etc/hosts` before using DNS?

Comment: My most common use case is to resolve hostnames from `/etc/hosts` before DNS, which is useful for Webserver and other network tests. But I (and other sysadmins) use getent for other things as well, such as troubleshooting LDAP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dscacheutil` is probably the best way to do this. It doesn't emulate the usual search process, it *uses* it, so you'll actually get the same results as a standard lookup (including caching, /etc/hosts, computer records in directory services, DNS, mDNS for .local names, etc).

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name www.apple.com
name: e3191.c.akamaiedge.net
alias: www.apple.com www.isg-apple.com.akadns.net www.apple.com.edgekey.net 
ip_address: 69.192.45.15

$ dscacheutil -q host -a name gordons-mbp.local
name: gordons-mbp.local
ipv6_address: fe80:5::e6ce:8fff:fe50:136

name: gordons-mbp.local
ip_address: 192.168.10.249

$ dscacheutil -q host -a ip_address 127.0.0.1
name: localhost
alias: 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa 
ip_address: 127.0.0.1

$ dscacheutil -q user -a name gordon
name: gordon
password: ********
uid: 501
gid: 20
dir: /Users/gordon
shell: /bin/bash
gecos: Gordon Davisson
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [How to emulate Unix’ getent with MacOSX’s dscl](http://zzamboni.org/brt/2008/01/21/how-to-emulate-unix-getent-with-macosxs-dscl/).  Since you have scripts that make use of `getent`, you may wish to pursue a script as a wrapper around dscl.

Answer (score 1):

It's not rocket science to scrounge the getent source from OpenSolaris (or some other OS, I'd try one of the BSDs rather than Linux) and port it; I got that to work mainly by just disabling the stuff that macOS didn't have any equivalent for (netmasks and project - Solaris specific).  Or one can write it in perl fairly easily.  Someone did a limited one a long time ago, and I did a more complete one; it doesn't support ethers because there's no standard lookup for that from perl, but the rest seems to work ok.

[getent.pl](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10AMsE9nAhOdDAjoM3sQs4gCswpuyyj73/view?usp=sharing)